# Change windows 10 date with c#

Tags: c#, date

I need to change the date of my laptop with Windows 10 using C#. I had made an app in C# back when I used Windows 7 and it worked perfectly, but it no longer works, so I had to make some adjustments. I am currently running the app as admin and have turned off set time automatically, but it still doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
void setDate(string dateInYourSystemFormat) {
    var proc = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    proc.UseShellExecute = true;
    proc.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Windows\System32";
    proc.CreateNoWindow = true;
    proc.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe";
    proc.Verb = "runas";
    proc.Arguments = "/C date " + dateInYourSystemFormat;
    try {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(proc);
    }
    catch {
        MessageBox.Show("Error to change time of your system");
        Application.ExitThread();
    }
}
```

Please help me change the date in Windows 10 with C# code.
I got this code from another post in stackoverflow and it said it was tested in Windows 8, but I can't seem to make it work in Windows 10.

Comment: Silly question. What .net version is  your application, and do you have this .net version installed on your new windows 10 laptop? Also, what errors are you seeing?

Comment: I am using .Net Framework 4.5, and there is no error, it just executes and nothing happens. I already have this .Net Framework, because it comes included in windows 10, I already tried installing it and I received that message.

Comment: This works on my machine with this call:

            setDate("4/22/2017");

Comment: I tried with my date format, which is from central america, and it worked the first time, but not the second or third, and I don't know how to replicate. Could you please give me the steps to replicate this in my project? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: Untested code (not willing to fool with my PC date/time).

Perhaps you could try the proper Windows API?

```
public struct SYSTEMTIME {
    public short year;
    public short month;
    public short dayOfWeek;
    public short day;
    public short hour;
    public short minute;
    public short second;
    public short milliseconds;
}

[DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool SetSystemTime(ref SYSTEMTIME time);

void setDate(DateTime aDateTime) {
    var aSYSTEMTIME = new SYSTEMTIME();
    aSYSTEMTIME.year = (short)aDateTime.Year;
    aSYSTEMTIME.month = (short)aDateTime.Month;
    aSYSTEMTIME.day = (short)aDateTime.Day;

    SetSystemTime(ref aSYSTEMTIME);
}
```